# Child div is not respecting height of parent even though parent height is set

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to use grid to layout a SPA that only smaller sections of the page scroll. I've read all around about setting the height from the child all the way to root to get it to respect the height, but I can't seem to actually get it to work. The fake image in the jsfiddle is much larger than can be displayed, but I can't get the div containing it to respect the height and scroll on it's own. Instead it just tries to grow past the end of the screen without scrolling. If I take out the `overflow:hidden` on the body it scrolls, but it scrolls everything instead of just the one div.

Here is a fiddle with the smallest repro I could find.

https://jsfiddle.net/64q8ud1z/1/

I'm sure it's something simple, but all the various ways of setting height and having it flow down to the children hasn't seemed to work, and I'm not sure what I'm screwing up in this case.

Comment: missing `min-height: 0;` in the first grid inside the body then in the next nested one